# Nested populate filteration is MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nodes

I have the following code that works fine;

```
return await Order.find({}).populate({
  path: 'items.product',
  select: "title price user",
  populate: {
    path: 'user',
    select: "_id name"
  }
})
```

Is it possible to add a query that match the user's name at nested populate and show only matched results like:

```
return await Order.find({}).populate({
  path: 'items.product',
  select: "title price user",
  populate: {
    path: 'user',
    select: "_id name",
    match:{name: "name of the user"}
  }
})
```

because this code always shows all orders even if the nested populated user's name doesn't match.

What I want is that if the user's name doesn't match then it should not show any order result at all. I don't know whether I managed to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

When executing `await Order.find({}).populate({`, Mongoose first sends the `find` to the mongod server and returns a cursor, which is passed on to populate.

Populate then retrieves each document from the cursor, and sends a separate `find` to the `user` collection to retrieve the matching document(s), and iterates that cursor, placing the retrieved documents in an array in the original document.

Populate can affect which documents are embedded in the original documents, but it does not have any capability to remove documents from the original result set.

The `match` passed to populate will mean only matching users get added to the original document, so you should be able to use `filter` to eliminate any documents in the result that contain no users.

Comment: Thanks. So whats the solution in here?

Comment: use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: You mean array.filter after getting the results? Or mongoDb filter?

Comment: Mongoose has already received the results from MongoDB before populate is called, so it's too late to do any filtering on the database size, and you'll need to use array.filter.